# jqgrid overriding the default URL in a Tree

Tags: jqgrid

I have a grid that has a datepicker with a button and a checkbox to reload the grid when the date changes. The datepicker is initialized to today's. This works fine. However I can't figure how to override the default url in the grid. Whenever the grid which is a tree is loaded it reads the default from the url configuration. Only when I click the button then it reloads the treee with the selected date. Even worst when I click in the icons in the tree to expand the child elements it overrides the date and all the loaded data with the value of the default URL. Can somebody tell me how to set the url properly? Also I don't understand why clicking in the elements reloads the tree since I have property loadonce=true.

thanks

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#list").jqGrid({
            url : "/reconcile?unMatchedOnly=true",
            datatype : "json",
            mtype : 'GET',
            colModel : [
            {name : "data.key.busnDate", label : "Business Date", hidden:false, sorttype:"date", width : 100 },
            {name : "data.product", label : "Product", sorttype:"string", width : 50, editable : false},
            {name : "data.quantityBought", label : "Quantity Bought", sorttype:"int", width : 100, editable : false},
            {name : "matches", label : "match", "edittype":"checkbox","formatter":"checkbox", width : 25, editable : false}
            ],
            cmTemplate: { width: 70 },
            treeGrid: true,
            pager : '#pager',
            treeGridModel: "adjacency",
            ExpandColumn: "data.key.busnDate",
            rowNum : 25,
            height: 'auto',
            rowList : [ 25,50,100,200 ],
            loadonce:true,
    });
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
            edit : false,
            add : false,
            del : false,
            view : true,
            search : true
    });
      $('#datePick').datepicker({
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var e = $("#list").data("events");
            if (typeof (e) !== "undefined" && typeof (e.reloadGrid) !== "undefined") {
                $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");
            }
        }
    }
    );
    $("#datePick").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
    jQuery("#list").setGridParam({url:'/reconcile?datePick=' + $("#datePick").val() + '&unMatchedOnly=' + $("#unMatchedOnly").val(),page:1});
    var url = '/reconcile?datePick=' + $("#datePick").val() + '&unMatchedOnly=' + $("#unMatchedOnly").val();
    $("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: url });

});

$('#showSelected').on('click', function () {
    var url = '/reconcile?datePick=' + $("#datePick").val() + '&unMatchedOnly=' + $("#unMatchedOnly").val();
    $("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: url });
    $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");
});
```

Comment: It's not full clear what you want to implement. The initial filling of the TreeGrid is especially unclear. You create the grid with `url : "/reconcile?unMatchedOnly=true"` making the corresponding request to the server and **immediately** try to change the `url` to another value (see `setGridParam` with `url` **twice** below). Are `#datePick`, `#unMatchedOnly` and `#showSelected` somewhere **outside** the grid? **Do you want that all requests to the server contains the values `$("#datePick").val()` and `$("#unMatchedOnly").val()`?** If it's so than your code could be much easier.

Comment: Do you load *all the data* at once or you load children of some nodes on expanding the node (it's default behavior). `reloadGrid` will be used by TreeGrid for loading of **child nodes**. What you want to do inside of `$('#showSelected').on('click', ....)`? Do you want to reload *whole TreeGrid* or you want to force loading of children of some node? Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid (free jqGrid, commercial Guriddo jqGrid JS or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)?

Comment: @Oleg yes I want any request to have the datePickand unMatchedOnly values always. I used "loadonce:true" because I send all the data parent and child. I don't want the grid to go back to the server unless the date or checkbox are changed. Basically I want to replace the url with a similar called to the $('#showSelected').on('click',...) but I can't figure how to tell the grid to use that function for all data loading.

Comment: @Oleg the version I am using is   jqGrid 4.15 with date  Date: 2017-07-09

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem, which you describe. You can try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/LocalAdjacencyTree-autoresized1__.htm) and examine the Network traffic, which you can see with respect of Developer Tools of Chrome or IE. Every reloading using "Reload" button in the toppager increase the value of `myparam` parameter. Click on `"Reload"` button under the grid reset the parameter and changes URL additionally. I see no problems with `trigger("reloadGrid")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem, which you reports. If you want to load the data of TreeGrid at once then you don't need to use `loadonce: true` option. Instead of that the items of data should contains the property `"loaded":true`.

If you need to send some additional parameter to the server then you should use `postData` parameter with properties defined as functions (see [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935)). You can just use

```js
url: "/reconcile",
postData: {
    datePick: function () { return $("#datePick").val(); },
    unMatchedOnly: function () { return $("#unMatchedOnly").val(); }
}
```

As the result *the current data* from `#datePick` and `#unMatchedOnly` will be sent to the server on every loading of the grid. To reload the TreeGrid you will need just use `$("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");`.

If you do loads the data of the grid on demand then expanding of nodes adds `nodeid`, `n_level` and `parentid` parameters to `postData` and the value of `treeANode` parameter will be changed from `-1` to the rowid of expanding node. To reset the parameters before reloading **you will need to reset `treeANode` parameter to `-1`**.

I don't know the format of the data, which returns `url: "/reconcile"`, but I suppose that you can use the following code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $grid = $("#list"),
        fullReloadOfTreeGrid = function () {
            var p = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam"); // get reference to parameters
            p.treeANode = -1; // be sure that we reload full grid
            $grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
        };

    $('#datePick').datepicker({
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            fullReloadOfTreeGrid();
        }
    });
    $("#datePick").datepicker('setDate', new Date());

    $grid.jqGrid({
        url: "/reconcile?unMatchedOnly=true",
        datatype: "json",
        postData: {
            datePick: function () { return $("#datePick").val(); },
            unMatchedOnly: function () { return $("#unMatchedOnly").val(); }
        },
        colModel: [
            {name: "data.key.busnDate", label: "Business Date",
              sorttype:"date", width : 100 },
            {name: "data.product", label: "Product", width: 50},
            {name: "data.quantityBought", label: "Quantity Bought",
              sorttype:"int", width: 100},
            {name: "matches", label: "match",
             "template: "booleanCheckbox", width : 25}
        ],
        cmTemplate: { width: 70 },
        treeGrid: true,
        pager: true,
        treeGridModel: "adjacency",
        ExpandColumn: "data.key.busnDate"
    }).jqGrid('navGrid', {
        edit : false,
        add : false,
        del : false,
        view : true
    });

    $('#showSelected').on('click', function () {
        fullReloadOfTreeGrid();
    });
});
```

As I wrote before, resetting of `treeANode` to `-1` will be *not required* if you really correctly loads all the nodes at once (with `loaded:true` property in all nodes).

Comment: I basically copy your code and it all start working fine now. To my data I added a column loaded with a value of true and now it does not go back to the server. Thanks